Infinitesimal transformation and weight of canonical momentum for the massless Klein-Gordon theory
Consider the massless Klein-Gordon theory in $3+1$ dimensions. Its Hamiltonian is
\begin{align}
 H=\int d^3x\,\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi^2+\partial^i\phi \partial_i\phi\right)\,.
\end{align}
It is known that infinitesimal transformations of fields $\phi$ and $\pi$, from the canonical point of view, are (e.g., see Eq. (2.5) of Henneaux and Troessaert)
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Infinitesimal transformations Poincare}
 \delta_{\left(\xi^\perp,\xi^i\right)}\phi=\xi^\perp\pi+\xi^i\partial_i\phi\,,\quad \delta_{\left(\xi^\perp,\xi^i\right)}\pi=\partial^i\left(\xi^\perp\partial_i\phi\right)+\partial_i\left(\xi^i\pi\right)\,,
\end{align}
respectively. From the Lie derivative approach, I readily obtain the infinitesimal transformation for $\phi$ (see below), however, problems arise for $\pi$. How can I obtain the above result from the Lie derivative point of view?
My attempt
Hamilton's equations are
\begin{align}
\pi=\dot{\phi}\,,\quad -\dot{\pi}+\partial_i\partial^i\phi=0\,.
\end{align}
With them, it is direct to find that $\delta_{\xi^\perp}\phi=\mathcal{L}_{\xi^\perp}\phi=\xi^\perp\dot\phi$. Using the first Hamiltonian equation, the latter is $\delta_{\xi^\perp}\phi=\xi^\perp\pi$. On the other hand, for vector field $\xi^i$, we directly find $\delta_{\xi^i}\phi=\xi^i\partial_i\phi$. Then the variation of the scalar field is $\delta_{\left(\xi^\perp,\xi^i\right)}\phi=\xi^\perp\pi+\xi^i\partial_i\phi$, in agreement with the equation above. Nonetheless, problems arise for the canonical momentum, since is a density of weight $-1/2$. The proof is given by the following.
The Hamiltonian must be invariant under change of coordinates, so it transforms as
\begin{align}
H'&=\int d^3x'\,\frac{1}{2}\left[\pi^2(x')+\partial^i\phi(x')\partial_i\phi(x')\right]\\
&=\int d^3x\,\left|\det J\right|\,\frac{1}{2}\left[\pi^2(x')+\partial^i\phi(x')\partial_i\phi(x')\right]\,,
\end{align}
where $J$ is the Jacobian. Therefore, we find that the squared canonical momentum transforms as
\begin{align}
\pi^2(x')=\left|\det J\right|^{-1}\pi^2(x)\,,
\end{align}
from where we find
\begin{align}
\pi(x')=\left|\det J\right|^{-1/2}\pi(x)\,.
\end{align}
This implies that the canonical momentum transforms as scalar with weight $-1/2$, so its Lie derivative has to be enhanced with the weight in the form
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_\xi\pi=\xi^a\partial_a\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi\partial_a\xi^a\,,
\end{align}
where $\xi=\left(\xi^\perp,\xi^i\right)$. Notice that when $a=i$, I may obtain an expression similar to $\delta_{\xi^i}\pi=\partial_i\left(\xi^i\pi\right)$, up to the factor $+1/2$ that spoils everything. Regarding the time-component, I don't know how to obtain it.
It seems that the canonical momentum is of weight $-1$, rather than $-1/2$.
